# How can one configure retry for IOExceptions in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I see that [Retry Filter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/v2.0.0.RC1/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/RetryGatewayFilterFactory.java) supports retries based on http status codes. I would like to configure retries in case of io exceptions such as connection resets. Is that possible with Spring Cloud Gateway 2?

Answer (score 2):

I was using 2.0.0.RC1. Looks like latest build snapshot has support for retry based on exceptions. Fingers crossed for the next release.
Here is an example that retries twice for 500 series errors or IOExceptions:

```
        filters:
        - name: Retry
          args:
            retries: 2
            series:
            - SERVER_ERROR
            exceptions:
            - java.io.IOException
```

Comment: Do you have the yml based configuration for the retry filter? Not found any documentation anywhere but can see the Filter in source code

Comment: @ArpanDas, I have updated the answer with an example. Please note that I had an issue getting it to work and opened an issue with the project: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/339